# Fetching web pages with javascript links from Java

Tags: java, parsing, web-crawler, html-parsing, nutch

I have a web crawler application in Java that needs to access all links in a web page. The problem is that in some pages, links are generated by a javascript function. Something like:

```
<a href="someJavascriptFunction()"> Lorem Ipsum </a>
```

I'm aware of [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). But in my tests, it was just way too slow for my purposes. A local page (in http://localhost/test.html) took almost 2 seconds to be fetched. Other remote web pages took much more time.

I would like the simpliest/fastest way to find all links in a web page, even the javascript ones in Java. (Solutions in C/C++ are welcome). 
I'm also aware that [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) (the crawler) has a link extractor from Javascript, but I'm not sure if that code could be "extracted" out of Nutch to be used in another context.

Answer (score 0):

Seems possible to extract usefull code from Nutch:

- http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/nutch/parse/js/JSParseFilter.java.html

Look at how the main method can be used as standalone JS link extractor.